# Write to file from Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Is it possible to have Chrome write the console output to a local file?

If not; Can I make an external call from the console to my server and save it there?

I know this can be done with devtool extended but I would rather do it from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write into a file in a local computer. It will lead to great security flaw.

Best way is to save the data in server.

The following **may** work, but need some server side work.

```
(function(console){

    var url = "domain.com/../userdata/"
    console.save = function(data, filename){
        var ajaxreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajaxreq.open("POST", url+filename, false);
        ajaxreq.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(ajaxreq.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(ajaxreq.status === 200)
                {
                    alert(ajaxreq.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
        ajaxreq.send(data);
    }
})(console);
```